# jquery image follow mouse when on click

Tags: jquery, html, image, mouse

I have read some tuto on jquery and how to do for an image follows the mouse.
I would like an image follows the mouse when I click on a button
I tried the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("myBtn").on('click', function () {
        $("#myImage").attr("src", "http://goo.gl/gCa93z")
    });

    function follow(e) {
        var xPos = e.pageX;
        var yPos = e.pageY;
        $("#myImage").offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }
});
```

so, set a src to my image when click event is detected, but just nothing append.

I tried something like that on http://jsfiddle.net/SYwba/92/ and it's work

my image

```
    <img id="myImage" src="" />
```

and my button

```
   <img id="myBtn" src="............" />
```

I tried to put an alert in "on click event", it's worke,

Thanks

Comment: so why the question if you made it work ?

Comment: works on jsfiddle, but not on my website

Comment: My image show during few miliseconds and hide just after

Comment: so there is something wrong somewhere else in your code

Comment: this is my html  : http://pastie.org/8449757 so loadRoll.js is http://pastie.org/8449762

Answer (score 0):

Go for the JqueryUI library

The draggable() might be the function you are looking for